# Grace period for users after re-enabling account disabled by PCI-DSS 8.1.4?

Tags: pci-dss, account-security, user-management

We have an automated system to disable user accounts that have seen no logins for 90 days. We also have a process of re-enabling such accounts (at the behest of the affected users), and this process involves contacting our customer support.

Alas, too frequently such re-enabled accounts are not actually logged into during the following 24 hours, and so they revert to their disabled state. Thus restarts another iteration of customer support contact.

I can find no documentation about the use case of re-enabling users. **How long a "grace period" may we give users to log into a freshly-re-enabled user account?**

Edit: The PCI documentation states (v3.2, p.69):

> **PCI DSS Requirement**
> 8.1.4 Remove/disable inactive user accounts within 90 days.
>
> **Testing Procedures**
> 8.1.4 Observe user accounts to verify that any inactive accounts over 90 days old are either removed or disabled.
>
> **Guidance**
> Accounts that are not used regularly are often targets of attack since it is less likely that any changes (such as a changed password) will be noticed. As such, these accounts may be more easily exploited and used to access cardholder data.

So the PCI-DSS document does not touch upon the topic of enabling disabled or blocked users.

One option would be to modify the "last login" date by postponing it a few days, as this would similarly postpone the next "harvest time" by the account-disabling task ... but I feel this is tampering with user data (and might show a normal user having logged in on a Sunday). A better, but more complex, solution would be to keep separate track of "last re-enabled", but even for that I would love to have some hard rule to code against.

Alternatively, it should be possible to disable user accounts already after, say, 70 days -- this possible inconvenience yields a 20-day window to sort out re-enabling AND first subsequent login without violating the 90-day rule.